# Tableview to Tableview

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview

I am a complete novice to coding and app building so apologies beforehand if this has a really easy solution. I have created an app that has a tab bar at the bottom and then `tableview` on one of the tabs. I have populated the cells in this `tableview`.

I am looking to be able to select a cell and it then go to another `tableview` with different categories based on the cell selection. E.g. First table view: Dogs, Snakes, Rabbits. Then the second table view: Labrador, Shitzu, poodle (if the 'Dogs' cell is selected) Python, Cobra, Rattlesnake (if the 'Snakes' cell is selected). Etc.

Comment: Research Storyboard segues. Segues navigate between ViewControllers. Essentially, when a cell is tapped you will invoke a segue to another ViewController.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to embed these two `TableViewControllers` in a **Navigation controller**.

You can do this in storyboard:

1. Select the `TableViewController` with the first table in it
2. In Xcode's menu bar: Editor > Embed In > Navigation controller
3. Create another `TableViewController` in the storyboard.
4. Ctrl+Drag a storyboard segue from a `TableViewCell` on the first `TableViewController` to the second `TableViewController`. Like @hw731 said, this will indicate that when a cell is tapped it will invoke the segue to the new TableViewController.

--Now move to code.

1. In the .m file for that first view controller you can pass whatever data you want to pass to the second VC. (like, the fact that they chose dog)
2. In the `-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender` method:

   - Grab the reference to the second view controller like so: `SecondTableViewController *secondTableVC = segue.destinationViewController`
   - Now you can say `secondTableVC.arrayOfItemsToDisplay = dogsArray;`

There are some interim steps in there like creating the class for the second TableViewController and connecting it. Hope this helps!

Comment: I kinda get this but I'm still a little lost as to how each cell will display text dependant on the previously selected cell. E.g do I need an if statement that states if cell on tableview 1 selected is dogs then display shitzu etc on tableview 2