# Display other data in tableview prototype cell dependant on a label in the previous tableview prototype cell

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uitableview

I have a tableview with a prototype cell with an imageview, and two labels. I want to be able to select one of the cells and go to another tableview based on the selection.

E.g. The first is a picture of the animal the name of it and a brief description under it. (Pic: of a dog,Title: Dog, Description: mans best friend). The second is the the breeds.

Comment: post your code you have tried so far.

Comment: It looks like you need to understand the basics of how a `UITableView` works, I suggest reading some tutorials or Apple's documentation; selecting a row and and pushing the correct view is as basic as it gets.

Comment: This seems to be identical to your first question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22310833/tableview-to-tableview (for which you already got an answer) and also similar to your second question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22490160/tableview-to-tableview-and-hierarchical-data-models. If you don't get satisfying answers, please try to *improve* the question instead of just repeating it.

Comment: JMarsh I understand how to push details to a new view but what I don't understand is how to change the details. E.g. I can create a tableview with pic, title & description and then push this to a view controller. But what I don't know is how to change the label in the new cell to display something associated to the previously selected cell

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried segue? If you're using storyboard in your project, this is the easiest way you can get it done. Take a look at this doc: [Interface Builder Help - Adding a Segue to a Storyboard](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-interface_builder/articles-storyboard/StoryboardSegue.html).

In the storyboard, you will hit control and select the prototype cell, and drag to the other view controller you're bringing your user to. Give the segue a name, then you can pass on the data by handing it in prepareForSegue:sender:, check if identifier first of course.

However, if you're not using storyboard, you can do it the old fashion way by implementing tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath: (see UITableViewDelegate) in your controller. Check which cell is selected, then alloc and init your destination view controller, and push it to the view stack.

Without any code or details, this is what I can suggest.

Comment: I know how to do basic segue. At the minute I have 2 tableviews. One populated as I want then when i select a cell it just displays a blank tableview. I want to show different data the is a subcategory of the previous tableview but i don't know where to start

Answer (score 0):

The code is as follows which shows my array of items for tab2viewcontroller.m (which is a tableviewcontroller). This is tableview 1. I then want to show the subcategories for each subject in tableview 2 which I have called tab2categoriesviewcontroller

```
[super viewDidLoad];


_tab2Title = @[@"Benefits of an active lifestyle",@"Influences on active lifestyles",
@"Exercise and fitness",@"Physical activity",@"Personal health",@"The mind and body",
@"The cardiovascular system",@"The respiratory system",@"The muscular system",
@"The skeletal system"];
```

Do I need to create an array for each category within my tab2categoriesviewcontroller.h e.g.

```
_benefit = @[@"The three categories of healthy active lifestyles", @"Benefits of taking part in physical activity"];
_influences = @[@"etc....
```

and then create an IBOutlet for the label within the tab2categoriescell.h and place a label on the second tableview prototype cell and call it `categories`

This is where I am stuck if the above is correct...

Do I use an if statement for the segue? is this even possible? Do i put this in the `viewdidload` of `tab2categoriesviewcontroller.m`? Do I need to import `tab2viewcontroller.h` to `tab2categoriesviewcontroller.h`? e.g. `if tab2cell UILabel = @"benefits of and active lifestyle" then categories equals _benefits`

I know this last section is completely wrong but as I say I am a total rookie and am in need of help

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to push to the next tableview, however this is only for one set of subcategories and they are displayed no matter which cell I select. The code I have is as follows:

```
[super viewDidLoad];

_category = @[@"Physical, mental & social wellbeing",
              @"Benefits of participation in physical activity",
              @"Reasons for participation in physical activity"];

.
.
.

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{

    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return _category.count;
}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"categoryTableCell";
Tab2CategoryCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

long row = [indexPath row];

cell.categoryLabel.text = _category[row];

return cell;
}
```

Not sure how to go about adding other categories and it displaying different arrays based on the selected row